# Windows Disk Spanning : is there a 2TB limit when trying to span 2x 1TB disks?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, azure, storage

I'm trying to create a 2TB data disk for my Azure VM (classic; Standard A4 (8 Cores, 14 GiB memory)). It's not allowing me -> saying the largest size is 1TB.

So I thought I might try and create 2x 1TB's and "Disk Span" them. When I do this, I can't get the full 2TB. just ... 1TB (so, why bother spanning, then?)

[image]

Is this a limit enforced by:

- Azure?
- Windows 2012 Datacentre R2?
- The fact that I'm in a Classic VM?

and here's the problem when I try and make a disk greater than 1TB:

[image]

Please help!

Comment: I think perhaps that dialog is asking you how much *of the disk you have currently selected* you want to use as part of the spanned volume?  So if you wanted you could tell it to use 80,000MB on disk 15 and 70,000MB on disk 16 and get a 150,000MB spanned volume?

Comment: AH! so you're saying, that data is for `DISK 15` _only_ and of course, it will change if I select `DISK 16` ? Good idea - i'll give it a go, tomorrow when I'm back at work.

Answer (score 0):

I still went ahead and tried it out. And .. it made a 2TB disk????

[image]

But that dialog window says the max space would be 1TB?

[image]