# Trying to speed up copying some Sql data files between two VM Data Disks

Tags: azure, storage, copy

I need to move my Sql Server data from the existing Azure data disk to a new one. When I try and copy the existing files from the 'old' Disk over to the 'new' Disk it says it will take about 10 1/2 hours. URGH. That seriously hurts.

[image]

Yep - the picture does say that the total of these files is `860GB`.

This is [related to a previous question](https://serverfault.com/questions/993709/windows-disk-spanning-is-there-a-2tb-limit-when-trying-to-span-2x-1tb-disks) I had/have about VM's + disks ... so the destination disk (in this case) is a 2x 1TB attached disk which is dynamic + disk spanned == 1x 2TB disk.

Info on the two attached disks (which are spanned as one):

[image]

Both are the same as that.

Are there any other tricks I can try and leverage to increase performance for this copy?

EDIT:

- The VM above is a `(classic) Standard A4 (8 Cores, 14 GiB memory)`
- I'm also hoping to do the same on another VM which is a `(classic) Standard D13 (8 Cores, 56 GiB memory)`.

Also trying to use Premium SSD but I can't :/

[image]

Here's an example of trying to create a Standard SSD (hint: there is no option):

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect your being limited by the disk throughput because you're using standard storage. The best solution would be to switch to using premium storage but I suspect you are running a VM SKU that does not support it. So next best thing would be to switch to using Standard SSD storage, which will work on any VM size and should up your throughput.

If you can't do that, then the other option would be to look at using larger standard disks to get more throughput, going to an S70 will get you 500 MB/s, however, then you are stuck with that size.

You also don't mention what VM size you are using. Disk performance can be throttled on some of the smaller VMs so you also want to check that.

Comment: Thank you @samcogan for the answer. I'll update my question with info about the VM size, etc. I'll also Try upgrading to Standard `SSD` storage and see if that helps (and by how much). I'll also check my _other_ VM which I also need to do this too, and see if Premium is an option, there.

Comment: Interestingly, I don't have an option to get Standard _SSD_ ?? Attached is an image of trying to select Premium SSD. So then I'm on an Dev/Test pricing tier and I cannot upgrade to a `DS` or `GS` VM :/

Comment: If you select standard, do you not then have the option to use SSD?

Comment: Updated OP with screenie. Looks like I cannot. Right now, I'm looking into updating my servers from Classic -> ARM and then this should allow me to resize the disk. I'll keep you posted with results.

Comment: Yeah, I just realised you are using classic, which means you are going to be using unmanaged disk. Standard SSD is only available on Managed disks. I would recommend moving to ARM and managed disks.

Comment: Yep - the ARM idea is what I'm trying to resolve now, to then be able to do all of these things :) Cheers for the help, really appreciate it.